SAP API for data retrieval into SAP BO/Webi
I have a few questions with reference to this sentence 'Generic JDBC/ODBC API, requiring to implement a custom JDBC/ODBC driver'. The intent is to use the API to retrieve the data from other database e.g. SQL for SAP BO/Webi consumption.
What is a generic JDBC/ODBC API? How do we get the installer for this? I'd appreciate some insights into its functionality and purpose.
What are the customisation required for the JDBC/ODBC driver?
How to go about implementing a custom JDBC/ODBC driver to integrate the API?
Any guidance or explanations on these points would be immensely helpful. Thank you in advance for sharing your expertise!
Existing JDBC driver did not have the capability for the API integration.
